# How to create app in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create app in facebook but it is giving error while adding **site url and app domain** field 
**error message for site url :** *"Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can."*
**error message for app domain :** *"This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: www.my-domainname.com"*

Comment: Did you set call-back or redirect URL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message says, your site/canvas/etc... URL's have to be derived from your app-domain.

So if your **app domain** is: *example.com*

Your **site url** needs to contain this domain. So you can use for example:

- **https://example.com/myapp**
- **https://example.com/mysupercoolapp.html**
- *[...]*

That, for example, would not work:

- **https://some-other-domain.com/myapp**

**Additional Notes**

- Always fill in your app domain first
- Make sure not to put protocol information into your app domain, just use your plain domain name (***example.com*** instead of **www.example.com** or **https://example.com**)
- As of facebooks new app control panel the protocol you have to use for your site/canvas/tab url has always to use the **https** protocol
- Your app name is completely independent of of your URL settings

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me is it compulsory to have app name same as folder name?

Comment: like i have created app by name test1, app donmain example.com and site url is example.com/test123

Comment: I'm glad you got it, your second comment here had it all right, what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: Hey, actually i was trying to **Add Platform** as **Website** while creating app so i didn't get field for _canvas url_ and _secure url_ but when i selected **add platform** as **App on Facebook** then i got both fields and i was able to create **app domain**

Comment: I created **App Domain** as you said and **canvas url and secure url** as per **site url** given by you

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the website URL. On the app settings, you need to enable the "Website" platform and set the necessary URL there. (If it's not appearing, click "Add Platform".)

Comment: Took forever to find where TF this setting was, thanks.  SO much easier to integrate Twitter.